# java bigtable hbase client failing with "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I've been getting intermittent errors when using the java-bigtable-hbase client. I'm using the package `com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-hbase-1.x-hadoop:1.27.1`.

These are the errors I'm getting (****** indicates internal libraries)

```
156991468 [grpc-default-executor-2434] ERROR c.g.c.b.hbase.AbstractBigtableTable - Encountered exception when executing checkAndPut.com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.async.AbstractRetryingOperation.getBlockingResult(AbstractRetryingOperation.java:423)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableDataGrpcClient.checkAndMutateRow(BigtableDataGrpcClient.java:307)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableDataClientWrapper.checkAndMutateRow(BigtableDataClientWrapper.java:144)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.AbstractBigtableTable.checkAndMutate(AbstractBigtableTable.java:465)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.AbstractBigtableTable.checkAndPut(AbstractBigtableTable.java:391)
    ********
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
    ********
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.Contexts$ContextualizedServerCallListener.onHalfClose(Contexts.java:86)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:331)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:866)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
",
```

Previously I was using `com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-hbase-1.x-hadoop:1.14.1` and was getting a similar "Received Rst Stream" errors:

```
ERROR c.g.c.b.hbase.AbstractBigtableTable - Encountered exception when executing checkAndPut.com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: HTTP/2 error code: INTERNAL_ERROR
Received Rst Stream
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:524)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.async.AbstractRetryingOperation.getBlockingResult(AbstractRetryingOperation.java:455)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableDataGrpcClient.checkAndMutateRow(BigtableDataGrpcClient.java:291)
    at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableDataClientWrapper.checkAndMutateRow(BigtableDataClientWrapper.java:144)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.AbstractBigtableTable.checkAndMutate(AbstractBigtableTable.java:465)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.AbstractBigtableTable.checkAndPut(AbstractBigtableTable.java:391)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.AbstractBigtableTable.checkAndPut(AbstractBigtableTable.java:370)
    ********
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing these errors? Anyone run into anything similar?

**UPDATE:**

I'm seeing these sporadic failures on a number of the `table.checkAndDelete` and  `table.checkAndMutate` calls. This is what one of the `table.checkAndDelete` calls looks like:

```
internalTable.checkAndDelete(
    rowKeyBytes,
    FAMILY,
    QUALIFIER,
    CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL,
    BYTE_VALUE,
    new Delete(rowKeyBytes)
        .addColumns(
            FAMILY,
            QUALIFIER));
```

Comment: Do you follow any documentation and can you provide any reproducible code?

Comment: I have taken over maintenance of this project so I couldn't say what documentation was originally followed, but I have updated the question with an example of how I'm calling the `checkAndDelete` function.

Comment: Could you please recompile your code and check this [post](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable/pull/586/files) in github to fix the error and see if it helps.

Comment: That link is to the java-bigtable project, but I'm using the java-bigtable-hbase project. Also, there is another person with a similar [open issue](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/issues/3735) on the java-bigtable-hbase page.